# Best way to emulate the functionality of Python's "in" keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, python, linq

Looked around but didn't see this asked. I'm essentially wondering what the 'best' (fastest, most readable, most idiomatic, etc) way of doing this would be.

The context is that I have a LINQ query to filter based on a list of possible enum values and want to keep it as un-nested as possible. In python, it'd be something like

```
def GetItems(status_types:list)
    return filter(lambda item: item.Status in status_types, ALL_ITEMS)
```

I think in C# I might have to do an

```
ALL_ITEMS
    .Where(i => Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusEnum)
    .Intersect(status_types))
    .Contains(i.Status));
```

Is this reasonable? It seems a bit obtuse to me, though it might just be my own personal obtuseness coming into play.

*edit* I think I'm using Any() wrong here. Looking for the right linq thingo now, sorry. Changed to Contains, and added typeof(). That's what I get for just typing into the text box I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are overcompicating things using `Intersect`, since you are only interested in findinf IF `status_types` contains `i.Status`, not in the set intersection of them.

Anyway, both these should do the job, even though the first form looks simpler ( I came up with the second since you mentioned the use of Any):

```
ALL_ITEMS
  .Where(i => status_types.Contains(i.Status));
```

or

```
ALL_ITEMS
  .Where(i => status_types.Any(x=>x==i.Status));
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was overlooking something simple.

Comment: +1 for small `status_types` lists. For large ones converting it to `HashSet` before operation would be better.

Comment: @a p : yea, usually when things looks too complicated with linq, either you are missing something or you just shouldn't use it in that particular situation

Answer (score 1):

```
var itemsWithCorrectStatus = collection.Where(i=>status_types.Contains(i.Status));
```

This iterates over each item in collection, and checks whether i.Status is in status_types.  If it is, include it.  If not, exclude it.